# A statement from heapsort algorithm in clrs book

Tags: algorithm

please explain the underlined statement in the picture. It's from section 6.2 in CLRS. How is the subtree size 2n/3 at most ?

[image]

Comment: As given in the underlined statement, The worst case occurs when the bottom level of the tree is exactly half full. So try to draw a tree for worst case and try to figure out subtree's size for each nodes. You will get your doubt solved.

Comment: But shouldn't the worst case occur when the bottom level is completely full?

Comment: If bottom level is completely full maximum subtree size would be `n/2` because as given in the worst case, If last level is half full then the maximum subtree size will be size of left child of root node and that size would be `2n/3`. Now from there if we try to add nodes one by one to make last level completely full, Then also the size of root's left subtree would be same and maximum but now `n` keeps on increasing and the factor `2n/3` increases too. [1]

Comment: But as left subtree's size is same, we need to now change the equation to represent the size and to show a constant by the expression, It gets decreased while`n` increases. So at last when the level is completely full and if we try to represent the maximum size(which would be size of left-subtree or right-subtree of root) in terms of n, It can be represented as `n/2`.[2]

Comment: So 2 n/3 is a tight upper bound on the left or right subtree size which occurs when exactly half of the lowest level is full?

Comment: Yes. You can't get more value than that if you represent the size in terms of `n`.

Comment: Okay...  Understood...  Thanks

Comment: It's usually recommended to avoid posting text as images, as this makes the text in question unsearchable, making the question hard / impossible to find for those with the same question, significantly reducing the future value of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that balance in binary trees is generally a good thing for time complexities! The worst case time complexity occurs when the tree is the *most inbalanced* it can be. We're working with heaps here – heaps are [*complete*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#complete) binary trees. The most inbalanced a complete tree can have is when its bottomost level is *half-full*. This is shown below.

```
          -------*-------
         /                \
        *                  *
       / \                / \
      /   \              /   \
     /     \            /     \
    /-------\          /-------\
   /---------\                       <-- last level is half-full
```

Suppose there are m nodes in the last level. Then there must be m - 1 nodes remaining in the left subtree.

```
          -------*-------
         /                \
        *                  *
       / \                / \
      /   \              /   \
     / m-1 \            /     \
    /-------\          /-------\
   /--- m ---\
```

Why? Well in general, a tree with m leaf nodes must have m - 1 internal nodes. Imagine if these m leaf nodes represented players in a [tournament](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tournament-tree-and-binary-heap/), if one player is eliminated per game, there must be m - 1 games to determine the winner. Each game corresponds to an internal node. Hence there are m - 1 internal nodes.

Because the tree is complete, the right subtree must also have m - 1 nodes.

```
          -------*-------
         /                \
        *                  *
       / \                / \
      /   \              /   \
     / m-1 \            / m-1 \
    /-------\          /-------\
   /--- m ---\
```

Hence we have total number of nodes (including the root):

```
n = 1 + [(m - 1) + m] + (m - 1)
  = 3m - 1
```

Let x = number of nodes in the left subtree. Then:

```
x = (m - 1) + m
  = 2m - 1
```

We can solve these simultaneous equations, eliminating variable m:

```
2n - 3x = 1
      x = (2n - 1) / 3
```

Hence x is less than 2n/3. This explains the original statement:

> The children's subtrees each have **size at most 2n/3** – the worst case occurs when the bottom level of the tree is exactly half full